# Leaflet only loads the first row of tiles in my map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I'm not able to get Leaflet to load the tiles of my map past the first row in this Vue 3 component.  I've tried declaring the vertical size of its `div` several ways, as well as calling `map.invalidateSize()` when the component is mounted, but without any success.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

onMounted(() => {
  var map = L.map("map", { attributionControl: false }).setView([0, 0], 0);
  L.tileLayer("http://127.0.0.1:7800/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg", {
    maxZoom: 0,
    noWrap: true,
  }).addTo(map);
});
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Map Detail</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<style>
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 512px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if either or both will work but you can try

1. Setting the dimensions of #map like this

   ```
   #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(512px / 100%); // Set the height relative to the width of the parent element
   }
   ```
2. Setting the maxZoom to a higher value like 18 in tile layer, and set the zoom in map to 1

   ```
   import { onMounted } from "vue";
   import * as L from "leaflet";
   import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

   onMounted(() => {
     var map = L.map("map", {
       attributionControl: false,
       zoom: 1, // Set the initial zoom level to 1
     }).setView([0, 0], 0);
     L.tileLayer("http://127.0.0.1:7800/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg", {
       maxZoom: 18,
       noWrap: true,
     }).addTo(map);
   });
   ```

Comment: Didn't have any impact, but I appreciate the help @ceckenrode!